# Extract nested record fields using reflection

Tags: java, data-binding, record

[commons-beanutils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) can retrieve nested values from beans:

```java
public class Person {
  Address address;
  public Address getAddress() { return address; }
}
public class Address {
  String city;
  public String getCity() { return city; }
}

var p = new Person();
p.address = new Address();
p.address.city = "Malgudi";

BeanUtils.getNestedProperty(p, "address.city"); // ✅ Malgudi
```

How can this be achieved in a similarly compact way when the data types are records?

`BeanUtils` apparently does not support records:

```java
public record Person(Address address) {}
public record Address(String city) {}

var p = new Person(new Address("Malgudi"));

BeanUtils.getNestedProperty(p, "address.city"); // ❌ Unknown property 'address'
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't find a common library that could do this in a one-liner, there is a way to configure `BeanUtils` to achieve this with the help of [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind):

```java
//add support for Java records to Apache BeanUtils
var utils = BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().getPropertyUtils();
utils.addBeanIntrospector(context -> {
  var clazz = context.getTargetClass();
  var recordFieldNames = JDK14Util.getRecordFieldNames(clazz); //helper method from jackson-databind
  if (recordFieldNames == null) {
    return;
  }
  for (String name : recordFieldNames) {
    try {
      var getter = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(name);
      context.addPropertyDescriptor(new PropertyDescriptor(name, getter, null));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
      //accessor method of record field not found (should not happen)
    }
  }
});

var p = new Person(new Address("Malgudi"));

utils.getNestedProperty(p, "address.city"); // ✅ Malgudi
```